# Limiting download speeds with PHP

Tags: php, header

I have this code here, however i want to limit the speed the user can download at, how would i implement this into this code;

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-length: ".filesize("uploads/$filename"));
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$origname");
    readfile("uploads/$filename");
```

Thanks!

This is what i tried;

```
$download_rate = 100;
```

$origname = get_file_name($file[0]);

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-length: ".filesize("uploads/$filename"));
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\'$origname'");

    $local_file = "uploads/$origname";
```

// flush content
    flush();

```
// open file stream
$file = fopen($local_file, "r");

while (!feof($file)) {

    // send the current file part to the browser
    print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));

    // flush the content to the browser
    flush();

    // sleep one second
    sleep(1);
}

// close file stream
fclose($file);
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've tried what @mugur suggested then there might be an issue somewhere else. For example in your snippet it seems you've got a missing escaped quotation mark:

> header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$origname");

I guess it should be:

> header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$origname\"");

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/dl-speed-limit.htm

Comment: yeah i have read this one, however i really need a way to integrate it, as i have tried and failed!

Comment: well, what did you try? how did it fail? this seems like a good starting point, so don't ask everyone to redo what you've already done.

Comment: does it give an error, it downloads faster or how did it fail?

Comment: well basically, the download limit does work, but it doesn't show the file downloading, just downloads it in the background and says its finished once its done.

Comment: Yes because probably the file is put together serverside at a specific "download rate" and then sent over to your browser. To start the download and make it appear as a limited download you will need to make it via the Apache configuration and a good starting point would be this:  http://www.howtoforge.com/mod_cband_apache2_bandwidth_quota_throttling_p3

Answer (score 0):

In your while fread, just calculate bytes and timestamps. Then add a tiny pause using usleep.